# How to get the particular row value when click on edit button in php?

Tags: php, html

The following code is in tag_show.php.I have to show all the data from the database and I am trying to edit the database from php code so i form the edit button at the end of all row in html table.

```
echo"<br><br><br><br>
<table border='6' style= 'background-color: #FFFFE0; color: #761a9b; margin: 2 auto;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>tag_title</th>
      <th>description</th>
      <th>show_in_welcome</th>
      <th>status</th>

    </tr>
  </thread>
  <tbody>";


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_detail))
        {
            $_SESSION['tag_title'] =$row['tag_title'];
            $_SESSION['description'] =$row['description'];
            $_SESSION['show_in_welcome'] =$row['show_in_welcome'];
            $_SESSION['status']=$row['status'];

          echo
                "<tr>
                    <td>{$_SESSION['tag_title']}</td>
                    <td>{$_SESSION['description']}</td>
                    <td>{$_SESSION['show_in_welcome']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['status']}</td>
                    <td><form action='edit.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tag_title' value='".$row["tag_title"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='edit' /></form></td>

  </tr>\n";        
      }
```

and the edit.php is

```
<?php

session_start();


echo"<form action='tag_show.php' method='post'>

<br><br><br>

 Tag Title<br><input name='tag_title' type='text' value='{$_SESSION['tag_title']}'><br><br>

Description <br><input name='description' type='text' value='{$_SESSION['description']}'><br><br>

Show in welcome<br><input name='show_in_welcome' type='text' value='{$_SESSION['show_in_welcome']}'><br><br>

Status<br><input name='status' type='text' value='{$_SESSION['status']}'> <br><br>

 <input name='submit1' type='submit'  value='Update'>

 </form>";

 ?>
```

but the $_SESSION returns the last row value in HTML table. But i want the receptive row value when i click on edit button.

Comment: here session make no sense. each time loop runs previous value replaced therefore you are getting last value. Instead of you can use the concept of query strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a session variable to pass the value to `edit.php` file.

Hope there is a unique key to identify the record from database. I assume it as `recordid`. Pass this value to `edit.php` as a query string

**tag_show.php**

```
$output = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_detail)){
    $output '<tr>
    <td>'.$row['tag_title'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['show_in_welcome'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['status'].'</td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?editid='.$row['recordid'].'">edit</a></td>
    </tr>';
}
```

In **edit.php**, you can get the `recordid` from query string and retrieve the data from database to populate the form

```
<?php

if($_GET['editid']!=''){
    //get record corresponding to the 'editid' from database
    //I assume the record is for and store in a variable $editdata
?>
<form action="tag_show.php" method="post">
<br><br><br>
Tag Title<br><input name="tag_title" type="text" value="<?=$editdata['tag_title']?>"><br><br>
Description <br><input name="description" type="text" value="<?=$editdata['description']?>"><br><br>
Show in welcome<br><input name="show_in_welcome" type="text" value="<?=$editdata['show_in_welcome']?>"><br><br>
Status<br><input name="status" type="text" value="<?=$editdata['status']?>"> <br><br>
<input name="submit1" type="submit"  value="Update">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are never updating the session data with the information received from the form. You will need something like this somewhere in your code.

```
$_SESSION['tag_title'] = $_POST['tag_title'];
$_SESSION['description'] = $_POST['description'];
$_SESSION['show_in_welcome'] = $_POST['show_in_welcome'];
$_SESSION['status']= $_POST['status'];
```

A few things to consider.

- Make sure your db info does not overwrite the values after user submits form.
- Always sanitize/validate user input before using it (unlike the above code, since it's just an example).

Answer (score 0):

here session make no sense. each time loop runs previous value replaced therefore you are getting last value. Instead of you can use the concept of query strings. Instead of Printing Form print a anchor tag

```
 <a href='file.php?id='.$row["tag_title"]>Edit</a>
```

Being your tag_title unique.

```
  if(isset($_GET['id))
   {
     $id = $_['id']
     // Your code based on id
   }
```

Now using id run mysql query and select desired data and display in form

Answer (score 0):

Certainly your code will return the last row as the session array overwrites the previous row's value after every iteration. 
Make the session array as multi dimensional like $_SESSION[$id]["tag_title"] and then in your edit.php refer to the session array using the id value.

```
$_SESSION[$id] = array('tag_title' => $row['tag_title'], 'description' => $row['description'], 'show_in_welcome' => $row['show_in_welcome'], 'status' => $row['status'])
```

Then increment the $id after each iteration.